# $3^m+7^n$ is a perfect square!!

Tags: number-theory, real-numbers

Determine all pairs $(m,n)$ of positive integers such that $3^m+7^n$ is a perfect square

when n and m are both odd $3^m+7^n$ isn't a perfect square. and when n and m are both even $3^m+7^n$ isn't a perfect square. But I can't figure out the other cases.

Can someone helps me!

Comment: Isn't $$16=7^1+3^2$$?

Comment: The solution in the previous comment is the only one with $m,n\leq250$